# Getting repetition of same values multiple time while combining two queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I write two queries in mysql workbench at the time of executing the hole query i am getting the same value. what should i do?

This is my query bellow

```
Select * 
from 
  (
    (select division.name,
            date(meter_data.reading_date),
            sum(meter_data.meter_delta) 'Gas Consumption (m3)'
     from meter, meter_data, division
     where meter.meter_id = meter_data.meter_id 
       and meter.division_id = division.division_id
       and Date(meter_data.reading_date) between '2018-04-01' and '2018-05-03' 
     group by date(meter_data.reading_date) 
    ) as table1,

    (Select Date(receipt.receipt_date), 
            sum(case receipt_item.item_name 
                    when 'Gas' then receipt_item.item_amount else 0 
                end) 'Gas Purchase'
     from receipt_item, receipt
     where receipt.receipt_id = receipt_item.receipt_id
       and Date(receipt.receipt_date) between '2018-04-01' and '2018-05-03'  
     group by Date(receipt.receipt_date)
    ) as table2
  );
```

while executing the queries separately each query returns the exact 33rows but combinedly it returns 1089 rwos

for example i am getting this here all the repetition of same data

[image]

but need to show like that (this one is demo image)
[image]

Comment: This is how cross product works `33 * 33`

Comment: how can i solve this issue?

Comment: What do expect ? It should return 33 rows after combine ? You need to join these 2 clauses based on same attribute

Comment: Please, explain what is the desired output. How so you want to combine your tables?

Comment: please see my question i explained there

Comment: So you want have a single cell for the zone spanning over multiple rows? That's not possible and it's not a MySQL problem. The rows contain the correct data, obtaining that output is a matter of display.

Comment: please see the Gas consumption forget the zone

Comment: I'm still not getting what you're asking. Please, provide a minimal working example of what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem with my queries the queries should like that beloow

```
Select * 
from 
  (
    (select division.name,
            date(meter_data.reading_date) AS reading_date,
            sum(meter_data.meter_delta) 'Gas Consumption (m3)'
     from meter, meter_data, division
     where meter.meter_id = meter_data.meter_id 
       and meter.division_id = division.division_id
       and Date(meter_data.reading_date) between '2018-04-01' and '2018-05-03' 
     group by date(meter_data.reading_date) 
    ) as table1,

    (Select Date(receipt.receipt_date) AS receipt_date, 
            sum(case receipt_item.item_name 
                    when 'Gas' then receipt_item.item_amount else 0 
                end) 'Gas Purchase'
     from receipt_item, receipt
     where receipt.receipt_id = receipt_item.receipt_id
       and Date(receipt.receipt_date) between '2018-04-01' and '2018-05-03'  
     group by Date(receipt.receipt_date)
    ) as table2
  )
WHERE table1.reading_date = table2.receipt_date;
```

this solve my problem